Spectral theorem for isometries
I will soon have an exam, and there is something that I simply don't understand: the spectral theorem for orthogonal matrices/endomorphisms (isometries).
$\phi$ is an isometry $\Leftrightarrow$
There is an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ (n-dimensional euclidian vector space) such that $_{\mathcal{B}} [ \phi ] _{\mathcal{B}}$ is a matrix of the form
$\begin{pmatrix}
 E_k \\
  & -E_l \\
  & & R(\theta_1) \\
  & & & ... \\
  & & & & R(\theta_m)
\end{pmatrix}$
where $E_k$ and $E_l$ are the identity for some $k,l \in \mathbb{N}$ and the $R(\theta_i) \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ are rotation matrices with some angle $\theta_i \in (0, \pi)$.
But where do the $\theta$'s come from? What angles are they exactly? And what do we gain from this form of matrix? How do we find it?
Does anyone maybe know some example or an assignment (where we need this) to understand this better?
Thanks in advance!

It's not clear what you mean by this. Let's take the $n = 2$ case to be really specific: in this case there are two kinds of linear isometries, namely rotations by some angle $\theta$ or reflections through some line through the origin. It's not clear to me what it means to ask "where $\theta$ comes from" here. $\theta$ is the angle it rotates by. Are you asking how to compute the angles?

@QiaochuYuan I know that if we have a real $2 \times 2$-matrix then $\theta$ is the angle of rotation in the euclidean plane. I didn't know how to imagine that in this case with a $n \times n$-matrix but I realize that you probably cannot imagine that so the question is useless. The rest still stands, especially an application would help.

This is just the spectral theorem. The rotation matrices correspond to pairs of complex eigenvalues - since the matrix has real entries, if $z$ is an eigenvalue so is $\bar{z}$, and the associated eigenvectors are also complex conjugates of each other. Changing that back into a real-valued matrix w.r.t a basis consisting of real vectors yields a rotation matrix.

you can find a chapter on this on page 112 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/linalg.pdf
